# MVC set value to integer property of an object in session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

I have Customer class

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname{ get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string MobilePhone { get; set; }

    public int Type { get; set; }
}
```

In Index method of HomeController, I have created an instance of Customer and set values to properties.Then I stored it in session to get the object in Index(HttpPost) method which is in the same controller. In Index(HttpPost) method, I can get all the property values properly except 'Type' Property. When I get Customer object from session, 'Type' property of this object is always equal to 0.

```
public ActionResult Index(string id, string co)
{
    Customer cust = new Customer();
    cust.Name = "customer";
    cust.Surname = "test";
    cust.EMail = "test@test.com";
    cust.Type=2;

    Session["customer"] = cust;

    return View(customer);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    if (Session["customer"] != null)
    {
        customer = (Customer)Session["customer"];
    }
    //customer.Type is equal 0
}
```

What could be the reason and how can it be avoided?

Thanks for replies in advance

Comment: Did you make sure that `Session["customer"]` was not `null`?  Because if it was then you'll have that initial `Customer` that you created with all default values set to it's properties.

Comment: Yes. Other properties are not null or empty, they have the values which i set.

Comment: Your code looks totally fine to me. Are you very sure that this is the exact code in your project ? No types (in the session key) ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks OK (except typos in `cust.EMail` -> `cust.Email` and `return View(customer)` -> `return View(cust)`) I even added this to my project and it works pretty well...